# JSON loooping JSON return value Jquery

Tags: jquery

At present I am iterating over the value of objects from a query value and manually assigning them.
Is there a way to assign them automatically?

The code below is OK if all the fields exist in the JSON string but what if they don't? 
How can I iterate over only what is there? Is that possible?

```
.each(members, function (index, value) {
            $('#viewpane-table > tbody').append('<tr><td>' +
                GetEditButton(value.Name, value.InternalId) +
                '</td><td>' + value.Title + '</td><td>' +
                (value.Status != null ? value.Status.DisplayName : "") +
                '</td><td>' +
                (value.AffectedUser != null ? value.AffectedUser.DisplayName : "") +
                '</td><td>' + dateFromString(value.LastModified) + '</td></tr>');
```

Comment: did you try members.each(function(index,value)) ?

Comment: @Sekai what is the difference in that approach?

Comment: your approach is not covered in the official doc.
http://api.jquery.com/each/